# Is there a way to run each segment of a batch on different GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

So I am very new to Tensorflow and GPUs and I was wondering if I can feed different segments of my batch to different GPUs and aggregate the result at the end. What I mean is that, let's say that batch size in each epoch of my training is 1600 and I have 4 GPUs. Can I feed batches of size 400 to each GPU during each epoch of training and then aggregate the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. You will have to perform multi-gpu training.

Though in TensorFlow you can do a tower-based design where you collect and aggregate the gradients from each tower before backpropagation, it is not so simple and efficient.

You should use [horovod](https://github.com/uber/horovod) which is easy and efficient.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful. Do you know any implementation example that has done it manually?

Comment: [This example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus) is on TensorFlow website. It is quite basic.

You can find more advanced examples [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/tree/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks).